# what is the maximum rate limit (messages per second) that can be configured for a rsyslog server?

Tags: rsyslog

I want to configure a rsyslog server to store logs of 100 nodes. I will keep these logs in a separate directory based on their host name, but i am not sure what will be the maximum rate limit (messages per second) that a rsyslog server can handle.
There may be congestion if all nodes start sending messages due to which there may be message drop on server side.
can any one help me, what is the limit and what other problem that i may face?

Answer (score 1):

This depends heavily on your configuration:

- protocol you're using (UDP, TCP, RELP, whether you add SSL...)
- message size
- queue properties on your collector server (in-memory queues are faster)
- hardware and network

If you simply retrieve logs via TCP and use dynafiles to write logs based on hostname, a powerful machine may handle as much as the network can throw at it. On recent versions of rsyslog people report as much as 1M EPS, but you can expect at least 100K EPS even on a weak machine for "regular" syslog messages of under 1K each. I got 25K EPS with one core of my laptop and sending logs to Elasticsearch: http://blog.sematext.com/2015/05/18/tuning-elasticsearch-indexing-pipeline-for-logs/